# Catalina: Blutooth headphone disturbing noises

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, catalina

After upgrading to `Catalina` my `Sony WH-CH500` gives high pitch noises. I have tried to remove end reconnect it but didn't work. It does happen alot when playing video. Does anyone have similar problem?

Comment: How are you connecting?  I have several Sony (and other manufacturer) headphones and don’t get those types of sounds by BT.

Comment: Yes. Same headphones, same problem after updating to Catalina.